# Laravel pagination after ajax not working scripts

Tags: ajax, laravel

I use this method for pagination:

```
https://gist.github.com/tobysteward/6163902
```

When I click on pagination page, my other scripts on page not working after ajax. I need reload page, then scripts working.

I use simple script:

```
$("#select").on("change", function() {
     alert()
});
```

How I can fix this solution? I need load scripts ?

Comment: Any javascript in the ajax content does not get excuted. So perhaps you need to execute it manually in the .done() promise resolve function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you load your posts, you need to rebind any event. try something like:

```
function getPosts(page) {
        $.ajax({
            url : '?page=' + page,
            dataType: 'json',
        }).done(function (data) {
            $('.posts').html(data);
            //bind again
            $("#select").on("change", function() {
                alert();
            });
            location.hash = page;
        }).fail(function () {
            alert('Posts could not be loaded.');
        });
}
```